# How to get attribute value Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with Selenium in Python. I would like to get the value of an attribute ['href']  and check that it is different from '#', if yes
so click on the link if not out of the loop:

```
if not driver.find_element_by_link_text('»'):
        break
            # Open next page
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='»' and not(@href='#')]"):
        link=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "»")))
        link.click()
    else:
        break
```

Here is the source code of the web page:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
<li class="active"><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=1">1</a></li>
<li><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=37">37</a></li>
<li><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=2">»</a></li>
```

My code does not work and I get this error:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Are you getting any errors? Update the question with the relevant HTML and error stack trace

Comment: i get this error : AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Comment: Is this all of your relevant code? When and how do you create `soup`?

Comment: I have successfully got all data that exists in the first page and save them in a csv file,i want check if next page exist then click in the link and scrap but the problem is that even if the next page does not exist and the value of href = "#" I go to the page and therefore my program never stops.

Comment: @MohammedBenaou, where is your HTML for the next button? (I mean "»")

Comment: <li class="disabled"><a href="#">»</a></li>

Comment: Do not update your question with the code that you got from answer. If provided solution is not working - just leave comment under the appropriate answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try this,

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
e = []
for elem in elems:
    val = elem.get_attribute("href")

    if "#" in val:
        print("found # do nothing")
    else:
        print("click this link ",val)
        // click link
        e.append(elem)
// call click function
e[0].click()
```

Comment: but i want to acces in the link of the next page i mean "»"

Comment: I triedi sEnabled() and isClickable() but are not working for me

Comment: i get this error :
e[0].click()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Check the length of list using len(e)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **»** you don't need to get the value of an attribute *href*, rather simply surround the *block of code* to `click()` the element in a `try-catch` block as follows:

```
while True:
    try :
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pagination']//li/a[@rel='nofollow' and contains(.,'»')]"))).click()
        # do your tasks on this particular page
    except :
        print("No more pages left")
        break
driver.quit()
```