# selenium python link_text.click()

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a python selenium script to scrape the "Likibu.com",
it is a website that offers short-term accommodation such as Airbnb,I have successfully got all data that exists in pages and save them in a csv file,
my problem is that my program never stops because there is always a value in the variable "href" when I get to the front page my program stays running even the value of (href) is "#",so what i'm trying to do is that when i get to the last page my program stops right after the scrape and not click on the href = "#"
I managed this code as below :

```
if not driver.find_element_by_link_text('»'):
       break
 # Open next page
 driver.find_element_by_link_text('»').click()
```

here is the source code of the web page :

```html
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="disabled"><a href="#">«</a></li>
<a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=1">1</a></li>
<li><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39tuzgbpnycdv7tkj102g?guests=2&amp;destination_id=4094&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
<li><li class="active"><a class="" rel="nofollow" href="#">»</a></li>
```

Comment: What do you expect from `if not driver.find_element_by_link_text('»')`? If there is no such element, you will get `NoSuchElementException`. `break` (I suppose that provided code is a part of loop) will never be executed. Also note that I've already share the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529563/how-to-get-attribute-value-selenium-python/50530329#50530329) - leave comment under the answer if you need some clarifications instead of submiting new question regarding the same issue...

Comment: if the next page does not exist then break

Comment: Simply Just implement `try`/`except` construction as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529563/how-to-get-attribute-value-selenium-python/50530329#50530329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for a element and that element is always displayed. so it is going for infinite loop. you can check for the href attribute is equal to # as given below. It may solve your issue.

```
if driver.find_element_by_link_text('»').get_attribute('href') == '#':
       break
 # Open next page
 driver.find_element_by_link_text('»').click()
```

Comment: the same problem the program never stops the link is "https://www.likibu.com/fr/search/39v2zgbpnx3z3mf11102g?guests=2&destination_id=4074&page=3#"

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("your_element_id")
element.click()
```

Comment: but the id attribute does not exist